# Formatting array initializers with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, formatter

Is there any way I can instruct Eclipse's formatter to put each value in an array initializer on a new line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it this way:
windows/preferences/java/code style/formatter, then near the selected active profile click edit

then on the "Line Wrapping" tab

Choose "Expressions"->"Array initializers"

Under The list choose "Wrap all elements, every element an a new line"

Answer (score 1):

Go to windows/preferences/java/code style/formatter, then near the selected active profile click edit, then on the new lines tab there are 2 options for this.

Comment: I guess you are referring to "Array initializers" checkbox group in "Formatter" but these options only add a new line after/before the opening/closing brace. I would like to add a new line after each comma for each value in the array initializer.