# Make Aptana / Eclipse formatter ignore arrays

Tags: eclipse, formatting, aptana, formatter

See [Aptana PHP Formatter - use custom formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660933/aptana-php-formatter-use-custom-formatting-rules)

I don't want the formatter to add newlines for each element in the array, since that more often than not will make the array ***less*** readable..

Of course one can add // @formatter:off // @formatter:on statements around it, but is there a better way to make the Aptana formatter ignore (nicely hand-formatted) arrays entirely?

In other words: How do I make Aptana ignore arrays entirely or format them better.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution when using Eclipse with Aptana plugin:
 (you will have to open the .js file with the built in JS editor and format with it and then get back to Aptana).

[Formatting array initializers with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552192/formatting-array-initializers-with-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks. The Aptana equivalent is: Preferences-> Aptana Studio-> Formatter-> PHP-> Pencil (Edit)-> New Lines tab-> "Insert new line between array creation elements'. But the question I meant to ask was: How do I make Aptana ignore arrays entirely or format them better.